# How to fetch page list from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can download user events but not user managed pages. Why? What is the difference?

Using `react-facebook-login` to get `user access token`

`import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login";`

Adding Facebook login to the screen, it has the `pages_show_list` permission:

```
<FacebookLogin
appId={fbAppId}
autoLoad={true}
fields="name,email,picture"
scope="public_profile,pages_show_list"
onClick={this.componentClicked}
callback={this.responseFacebook}
```

And here is the handler:

```
responseFacebook = response => {
  this.setState({
    accessToken: response.accessToken,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    userID: response.userID,
    name: response.name,
    email: response.email,
    picture: response.picture.data.url
  });
  axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts&access_token='+response.accessToken)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("aaa " + response);
    console.log("bbb ");
  })
};
```

Second breakpoint will not be reached.

[image]

But get a lot of strange error:

[image]

Facebook API Explorer returns the data

[image]

Code is here: https://gitlab.com/j4nos/ticket-portal/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: you should add code and json data/response directly in stackoverflow, not as screenshots...

Comment: Hi! Code is here: https://gitlab.com/j4nos/ticket-portal/blob/master/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But get a lot oof strange error:

*Focus.*

The main part of importance here is that it shows that you are getting a 400 Bad Request response from the API, with that URL you tried to request there.

> `https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts&access_token=...`

How does the query string portion of a URL *start* again ...?

**Question mark**, not ampersand.